# Mini image browser (like on myfonts.com)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to make small image browser like the one used on Myfonts.com ([link](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/anatoletype/acuta-medium/)) in the sidebar under "More fonts like this".

I'm wondering if there is a jQuery plugin that could do that.

I know that this is some kind of carousel, but I couldn't find any with this cool resize function on scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you take the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) plugin, as it has a very good base, and modify it to your liking. You could combine it with the [jquery ui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) to somehow achieve the same effect as on Myfonts.com.

I did come across something similar although not exactly the same. It might help you figure out how the resizing effect is accomplished. See http://www.eogallery.com/ and http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel/demo/index.html

As of today I couldn't find any out-of-the-box plugin that does what you are trying to do, but maybe if you build this, you'll post it to the jquery gallery and everyone will live happily ever after :-)